# what is difference between these two expectation values?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

what is difference between these two expectation values $\langle \hat A \hat B\rangle$ and $\langle \hat B \hat A\rangle$?
where the $\hat B$ and $\hat A$ are two operators.

Comment: What are $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ in this case? If they do not commute, then the operator $\hat A \hat B$ and it's opposite aren't Hermitian in general, in which case it may not make sense to talk of their "expectation values" per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\langle \hat{A}\hat{B} \rangle -\langle \hat{B}\hat{A} \rangle = \langle \hat{A}\hat{B}-\hat{B}\hat{A} \rangle$$

So it is simply the expectation of the commutator.

Comment: Note that this difference is the basis of Heisenberg's uncertainty relations.